# Dendrogram y-axis labeling confusion

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have a large `(106x106)` correlation matrix in pandas with the following structure:

```
+---+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|   |         0         |        1         |        2         |        3         |        4         |        5        |        6         |        7         |        8         |         9         |
+---+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
| 0 |               1.0 |   0.465539925807 |   0.736955649673 |   0.733077703346 |  -0.177380436347 | -0.268022641963 |  0.0642473239514 | -0.0136866435594 |  -0.025596700815 | -0.00385065532308 |
| 1 |    0.465539925807 |              1.0 |  -0.173472213691 |   -0.16898620433 | -0.0460674481563 | 0.0994673318696 |   0.137137216943 |   0.061999118034 |  0.0944808695878 |   0.0229095105328 |
| 2 |    0.736955649673 |  -0.173472213691 |              1.0 |   0.996627003263 |  -0.172683935315 |  -0.33319698831 | -0.0562591684255 | -0.0306820050477 | -0.0657065745626 |  -0.0457836647012 |
| 3 |    0.733077703346 |   -0.16898620433 |   0.996627003263 |              1.0 |  -0.153606414649 | -0.321562257834 | -0.0465540370732 | -0.0224318843281 | -0.0586629098513 |  -0.0417237678539 |
| 4 |   -0.177380436347 | -0.0460674481563 |  -0.172683935315 |  -0.153606414649 |              1.0 | 0.0148395123941 |   0.191615549534 |   0.289211355855 |    0.28799868259 |    0.291523969899 |
| 5 |   -0.268022641963 |  0.0994673318696 |   -0.33319698831 |  -0.321562257834 |  0.0148395123941 |             1.0 |   0.205432455075 |   0.445668299971 |   0.454982398693 |    0.427323555674 |
| 6 |   0.0642473239514 |   0.137137216943 | -0.0562591684255 | -0.0465540370732 |   0.191615549534 |  0.205432455075 |              1.0 |   0.674329392219 |   0.727261969241 |     0.67891326835 |
| 7 |  -0.0136866435594 |   0.061999118034 | -0.0306820050477 | -0.0224318843281 |   0.289211355855 |  0.445668299971 |   0.674329392219 |              1.0 |   0.980543049288 |    0.939548790275 |
| 8 |   -0.025596700815 |  0.0944808695878 | -0.0657065745626 | -0.0586629098513 |    0.28799868259 |  0.454982398693 |   0.727261969241 |   0.980543049288 |              1.0 |    0.930281915882 |
| 9 | -0.00385065532308 |  0.0229095105328 | -0.0457836647012 | -0.0417237678539 |   0.291523969899 |  0.427323555674 |    0.67891326835 |   0.939548790275 |   0.930281915882 |               1.0 |
+---+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Truncated here for simplicity.

If I calculate the linkage, and later plot the dendrogram using the following code:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
Z = linkage(result_df.corr(),'average')
plt.figure()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20, 20))
axes.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=15)

dendrogram(Z=Z, labels=result_df_null_cols.columns, 
           leaf_rotation=90., ax=axes, 
           color_threshold=2.)
```

It yields a dendrogram like:
[image]

My question is surrounding the y-axis. On all examples I have seen, the Y axis is bound between 0,2 - which I have read to interpret as `(1-corr)`. In my result, the boundary is much higher. 0 being items that are highly correlated `(1-1 = 0)`, and 2 being the cutoff on lowly correlated stuff `(1 - -1 = 2)`.

I found the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175462/dendrogram-using-pandas-and-scipy) but [it does not agree with this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82326/how-to-interpret-the-dendrogram-of-a-hierarchical-cluster-analysis) and the [referenced lecture notes here](http://www.econ.upf.edu/~michael/stanford/maeb7.pdf).

Anyway - hoping someone can clarify which source is the correct one, and help spread some knowledge on the topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The metric, which has been used for the `linkage()` is the euclidean distance, see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py#L1118) and not the actual values. Therefore, it can go beyond 2 and it purely depends on the type of distance metric we use.

This supports the points, mentioned in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82326/how-to-interpret-the-dendrogram-of-a-hierarchical-cluster-analysis) answer.

> 1) The y-axis is a measure of closeness of either individual data
>   points or clusters.

Then, these distances are used to compute the tree, using the following calculation between every pair of clusters.

[**From Documentation:**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage)

[image]

In your mentioned sample,

Even though the individual values does not go beyond `(-1, +1)`, we will get the following dendrogram.

[image]

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
distance.pdist(df, 'euclidean')
```

The reason is that the distance array of size 45 (**`10 C 2`** - every pair of columns; ordering is explained [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L1764)) would have following values:

```
array([1.546726  , 0.79914141, 0.79426728, 2.24085106, 2.50838998,
       2.22772899, 2.52578923, 2.55978527, 2.51553289, 2.11329023,
       2.10501739, 1.66536963, 1.6303103 , 1.71821177, 2.04386712,
       2.03917033, 2.03614219, 0.0280283 , 2.33440388, 2.68373496,
       2.43771817, 2.68351612, 2.73148741, 2.66843754, 2.31758222,
       2.67031469, 2.4206485 , 2.66539997, 2.7134241 , 2.65058045,
       1.44756593, 1.39699605, 1.55063416, 1.56324546, 1.52001219,
       1.32204039, 1.30206957, 1.29596715, 1.2895916 , 0.65145881,
       0.62242858, 0.6283212 , 0.08642582, 0.11145739, 0.14420816])
```

If we build a random value matrix with uniform dist. `(-1, 1)` of size `(160, 160)`, the dendrogram would be something similar to this!

[image]

Hence, the solution for your problem is,

You need to convert the correlation values into some form of distance measure.

1. we could use the same [squareform()](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L2078) suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175462/dendrogram-using-pandas-and-scipy). This is a duct tape approach to achieve two aspects of a distance measure. It has to be zero [between same two points] and non-negatives for any two points. This can be achieved by subtracting each corr value from one.
2. Directly we can use the `distance.pdist` function with correlation as metric. The implementation is available [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L182). Remember to transform the dataframe, because we need correlation between each column and not row.

Example to understand the solution:

```
size = (10000,1)
col1 = np.random.randint(0,100,size) # base column
col2 = col1 * 0.9 + np.random.normal(0,2,size) # huge corr with small noise
col3 = col1 * 0.1 + np.random.normal(0,100,size) # uncorrelated column
col4 = col1 * (-0.5) + np.random.normal(0,1,size) # negatively corr

data = np.hstack((col1,col2,col3,col4))
df = pd.DataFrame(data , columns=list('ABCD'))

df.corr()

    A   B   C   D
A   1.000000    0.997042    0.029078    -0.997614
B   0.997042    1.000000    0.029233    -0.994677
C   0.029078    0.029233    1.000000    -0.028421
D   -0.997614   -0.994677   -0.028421   1.000000

#pdist_values = distance.squareform(1 - df.corr().values )
pdist_values = distance.pdist(df.T, 'correlation')
z = linkage(pdist_values, method='average')
dendrogram(z, labels=df.columns)
```

[image]

Comment: Glad, that I am able to help :).